# Div refresh using jquery doesn't show new content when there is new data in the database

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, jquery

I have created a php file with a div in it that is being refreshed every 10 secs. In this div the result from a query is loaded. Demo: http://mauricederegt.nl/test/test.php

It looks like it is refreshing the div, but if new data is added in the database, the div doesn't get the new data and keeps showing the old data.

I use the same page as the page that needs to be reloaded:

`$('#scoreboard-overview').fadeOut('slow').load('index.php #scoreboard-overview').fadeIn("slow");`

If I copy the sql query used in the div to an external php file (e.g. reload.php) and then call it like:

`$('#scoreboard-overview').fadeOut('slow').load('reload.php').fadeIn("slow");`

it works and the div shows the latest data. The problem is: I don't want to use another external php file.

How can I accomplish this?

I also tried to put the `$resulttt` query in the div, but this also had no effect. What am I missing?

Kind regards,

The code used in index.php:

```
<?php
    /////////////////////////////////////////////

    //mysql_connect(servername,username,password);
    //Here we connect to the database

    /////////////////////////////////////////////
//Get the data
$resulttt = mysql_query("SELECT fbID, highscore, stars, MIN(time) AS time FROM highscore GROUP BY fbID, highscore ORDER BY highscore DESC, time ASC LIMIT 7");



?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function()
{
$('#scoreboard-overview').fadeOut('slow').load('index.php #scoreboard-overview').fadeIn("slow");
}, 10000);
</script>
</head>
  <body>
    <div id="scoreboard">
        <div id="scoreboard-title">High scores</div>
        <div id="scoreboard-overview">
        <?php   echo '<ul>';
                $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($resulttt);
                $i = 0;
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resulttt)) {
                        $i = $i + 1;
                        $fb_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/'. $row['fbID']));
                        $fb_locale_str = $fb_data->locale;
                        $fb_name_str = $fb_data->first_name;
                        $fb_country_str = strtolower(substr($fb_locale_str, -2));
                        $flag_uri = 'images/flags/unknown.gif'; //display a general flag if unknown.
                        $row['fbnr'] = $row['fbID'];

                        echo '<li id="'. $row['fbnr'] .'">
                                <div class="userpicture"><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/'. $row['fbID'] .'/picture" alt="" /></div>
                                <div class="username"><p>'.$i.'. '.$fb_name_str.'</p></div>
                                <div class="userflag"><img src="'.$flag_uri.'" alt="" /></div>  
                                <div class="userholder">
                                    <div class="usertime"><p><img src="images/time.png" alt="" /><br>'. $row['time'] .'</p></div>
                                    <div class="userstars"><img src="images/'. $row['stars'] .'s.png" alt="" /></div>
                                    <div class="userscore"><p>'. $row['highscore'] .'</p></div>
                                </div>      
                            </li>';
                    }
            echo '</ul>'; ?>

        </div>
        <div id="scoreboard-bottom">end</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

I think I've found a workaround using `GET`, thanks to all for helping

Comment: have you thought about ajaxing in your extra page?

Comment: Yes but I can't use an external page. THis is because my original page uses fb login. Using an external page will give a fatal error because the session is expired (for the external page) so all must be done from index.php

Answer (score 2):

I can't imagine any browser is going to be happy about Javascript attempting to insert an entire HTML page (complete with `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags) into an element in an existing document. You want to put the contents of `scoreboard-overview` on the loaded page into `scoreboard-overview` on the existing page, so add a selector to your call to `.load()`:

```
$('#scoreboard-overview').fadeOut('slow').load('index.php #scoreboard-overview').fadeIn("slow");
```

Comment: Thanks. Changed the code to: `$('#scoreboard-overview').fadeOut('slow').load('index.php #scoreboard-overview').fadeIn("slow");` Your example uses the external file witch I want to avoid

Comment: @Maurice Ah, yes - copied the wrong line of code from the question to edit.